# Improving the speed of a web scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have created a web scraper to extract information of research papers that are published in a digital library ([sample document](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7507196)).

Basically I'm extracting the title, abstract and list of references for each paper and storing them in text files. This process is repeated for all the referenced papers also.

- I have used a queue to store the document IDs.
- I need to extract such information from atleast 5000 papers, but the program is too slow and  takes about 3 hours to go through 250-300 papers.

What are the possible ways of improving the speed of this scraper?

Here is the code:

```
# _*_ coding:utf-8 _*_
import urllib2
import json
import Queue

crawled = []

fo = open("paper.txt", "w")

class Paper(object):
    def __init__(self, paper_id):
        self.paper_id = paper_id
        self.title, self.abstract = self.fetch_data()

    def fetch_data(self):
        base_url = "http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/rest/document/{0}/{1}"
        data_url = base_url.format(self.paper_id, "abstract")
        response = urllib2.urlopen(data_url)
        html = response.readlines()
        data = json.loads("\n".join(html))
        title = data["title"]
        abstract = data["abstract"]
        return title, abstract

    def fetch_ieee_references(self):
        base_url = "http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/rest/document/{0}/{1}"
        data_url = base_url.format(self.paper_id, "references")
        response = urllib2.urlopen(data_url)
        html = response.readlines()
        data = json.loads("\n".join(html))
        references = []
        try:
            for ref in data["references"]:
                try:
                    ref_link = ref["links"]["documentLink"]
                    ref_paper_id = ref_link.split("/")[-1]
                    references.append(Paper(ref_paper_id))
                except:
                    pass
       except:
           pass
       return references
    def extract_paper(self):
        try:
            print "Paper ID"
            print self.paper_id
            fname = str(self.paper_id)
            fname = fname + ".txt"
            fcon = open(fname,"w")
            print
            print "Title"
            print self.title
            print >>fcon, self.title
            print "Abstract"
            print self.abstract
            print >>fcon, self.abstract
            print "References"
            for ref in self.fetch_ieee_references():
                print ref.paper_id, ref.title
                print >>fo, self.paper_id, ref.paper_id
        except:
            pass


def new_func():
    n_id = 6639344
    q = Queue.Queue()
    q.put_nowait(n_id)
    crawled.append(n_id)
    while not q.empty():
        p_id = q.get_nowait()
        paper = Paper(p_id)
        paper.extract_paper()
        for ref in paper.fetch_ieee_references():
            if ref.paper_id not in crawled:
                crawled.append(ref.paper_id)
                q.put_nowait(ref.paper_id)

new_func()
```

Comment: Almost all of times it depends on HTTP request/response time and availability of server. And it is not always under our control.

Comment: For code improvement and optimization on working code: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Along this comment, because the HTTP request is your bottleneck, focus on making this always running. You should not be analyzing text on the same thread in between HTTP calls. Try having one thread running through all ID's and queuing the results of your HTTP calls, and another thread building paper objects inputting the data from those results rather than doing the HTTP from the init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned by other users it mostly depends on the speed of the HTTP request so you are dependent on the server of the site. So to speed things up you can divide the papers between multiple processes.
Also I don't get why you read the html and then use json.loads you can just use json.load on the response, this will speed things up a little bit.